# Ubuntu 15.10 connect to VPN server on port 443 without certificate

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I need to connect to a VPN server from Ubuntu 15.10. I know gateway, port 443 username and password. Usually I connect from Windows using Forticlient, but there is no version of this software for Ubuntu.
I've tried through `Network Manager` > `Configure VPN` > `OpenVPN`. But this requires a certificate, which I don't have and it's not needed when I connect from Windows. I've tried to use `openvpn` from the command line, but failed to run it. I don't have sufficient Linux knowledge to conquer this task and would appreciate some help.

Comment: I also need the answer to this question. Is there any progress?

Comment: @ismailarilik Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to OpenVPN from Windows you must have profile/configuration file somewhere with **.ovpn** extension, quite sure it can be found from `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\`. When you open-up your configuration file at Windows you will see where certificates are located at your computer.

You can copy-paste your configuration from Windows to Linux (aswell certificates) but make sure you edit certificates locations.

After that, connect from command line at linux with your config file.

```
openvpn --config ~/workvpn.ovpn
```

Comment: The thing is that on Windows I use Forticlient, not OpenVPN. I'm not even sure that I'm connection to an OpenVPN server, I made this assumption based on the port 443, which I use in Forticlient settings. I definitely did not provide any certificate to Forticlient on Windows, and I couldn't find any it C:\Program Files(x86)\Fortinet\Forticlient.

Answer (score 0):

Good news: There is a [FortiClient for Linux](https://www.forticlient.com/downloads) (For Ubuntu and RedHat) At the link you can download the `.deb` or `.rpm` files.

Here you find [more detailed information](https://www.forticlient.com/repoinfo) for adding the package to your repositories.

**You can use FortiClient to connect to VPN Server without need to add the CA certificate. :)**

All that said, I have to admit that I tried to find a "pure" Ubuntu solution and it was to no avail. I encourage people to post an answer without FortiClient.

Note: As of 11-2020, The Forticlient is officially only available for Ubuntu versions 16.04 and 18.04., but I guess that now (4 years later) you are no more using the 15.10. as it is no more supported.